# Where do I place a period when a sentence ends with a quote?

Tags: punctuation, quotation-marks

Where do I place a period to end a sentence following a quote? Same thing with a question mark where the quote was interrogative. Does the "?" land inside or outside the quote, followed by a period?

> And he said, "I like trains."
>
> And he said, "I like trains.".

or

> And he said, "I like trains".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Periods that are part of the overall sentence go inside the quotation marks, even though they aren’t part of the original quotation: **And he said, "I like trains."**

Put the question-mark inside the quotation marks if the whole quotation is a question: **And he asked, "Do you like trains?"**

But if the overall sentence is interrogative, place the question-mark outside the quotation marks: **Wasn’t it Dickens who wrote, “It was the best of times, it was the worst of times”?**